# Troubleshooting errors occuring when installing Eigen3-library on vMicro

Tags: visual-studio, arduino

I am developing code for an Arduino/Genuino MKR1000 board. I use the vMicro add-on in Visual Studio 2019 for this purpose. As it turns out, installing libraries is fairly error-prone - at least I have had some troubles with it so far.

Now, I want to install the Eigen3 library ([here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)) in order to use some linear algebra easily. I have downloaded the library, unzipped and renamed it to "eigen" and pasted this folder into a path my IDE has told me it would be looking for libraries in: 
...\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\samd\1.6.21\libraries

When I include the library via `#include <eigen/Eigen/Dense>`, the library is found. However, when I compile the code, I get multiple errors related to this library, such as:

- 360:41: error: macro "max" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
- 371:41: error: macro "min" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
- 394:30: error: macro "min" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given

and so on.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem when installing Eigen-library in vMicro? Does anyone have a clue what might cause this problem?